# Find last row in group by query-SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have table in SQL Server. I want to find last row in each group. I tried with the following query, but it does not return exact result. ID column is PK and other columns are set to NOT NULL.

```
select ID, Name FROM 
(select ID, Name, max(ID) over (partition by Name) as MAX_ID
from Customer) x where ID= MAX_ID
```

To be more clear. I have 2 queries.First:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Ramiz_Musterija_RowNum]
@Datum DATE,
@BrojKamiona INT
AS SET NOCOUNT ON
SELECT Ime,MusterijaID,RowNum=ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Ime)FROM Musterije
WHERE Datum=@Datum AND BrojKamiona=@BrojKamiona  GROUP BY Ime,MusterijaID
```

And second one:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Ramiz_Musterija_FindLast]
@Datum DATE,
@BrojKamiona INT
AS SET NOCOUNT ON
SELECT a.* from Musterije a
JOIN (SELECT Ime, MAX(MusterijaID) AS MAXID FROM Musterije GROUP BY Ime) AS b 
ON a.MusterijaID = b.MAXID AND a.Datum=@Datum AND a.BrojKamiona=@BrojKamiona
```

Then LINQ query:

```
  var rowNumList = from f in customerFindLastList
                     join r in customerRowNumList
                     on f.MusterijaID equals r.MusterijaID
                     select new { r.RowNum };
```

I am trying to find last row in each row,then match this 2 queries on MusterijaID column.
Any help regarding this would be appreciated.
This is output of one group. Now, problem is that these two queries are matched on "4250" MusterijaID, but I need to match queries on "4229".

```
Ime MusterijaID
100//1  4246
100//1  4247
100//1  4248
100//1  4249
100//1  4250
100//1  4229
```

Comment: "*does not return exact result*" is **way** to vague. You need to be more specific. Show us some sample data and what you get. Or even better create an example on: http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: Assuming that "last row" means the one with the biggest `id`, then your query looks correct.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
select ID, Name 
FROM (select ID, Name, -- add other columns here
             ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by Name ORDER BY ID DESC) as MAX_ID
      from Customer) x
WHERE MAX_ID = 1
```

Comment: Why would this return different results than the OP's query?

Comment: @JW I finally found solution. I just had to add 

    OVER(ORDER BY Ime,MusterijaID) 
instead of 

    OVER(ORDER BY Ime)
in my SP "**Ramiz_Musterija_RowNum"**.

Thank you all for help.