# Show only rows with MAX(DATE) on a multiple joins query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to show only one row for every STO_PART, the one that has MAX(TRL_DATE)

I found that ROW_NUMBER()... may be useful, but I am not able to do it properly with a query with joins.

```
SELECT      STO_PART, STO_PART_ORG, STO_STORE, BIS_BIN, TRL_ORDER, TRL_DATE

FROM        R5STOCK inner join R5PARTS on PAR_CODE = STO_PART and STO_PART_ORG = PAR_ORG
            inner join R5BINSTOCK on (BIS_STORE = STO_STORE and BIS_PART = STO_PART and BIS_PART_ORG = STO_PART_ORG)
            left join R5TRANSLINES on (TRL_PART = PAR_CODE and PAR_ORG = TRL_PART_ORG and TRL_TYPE = 'RECV')

WHERE       PAR_NOTUSED != '+' and BIS_QTY > 0 and STO_STORE in ('116-01', '138-05', '156-01', '216-01', '228-01', '282-01') 
            and TRL_STORE = STO_STORE and TRL_ORDER is not null

GROUP BY    STO_PART, STO_PART_ORG, STO_STORE, BIS_BIN, TRL_ORDER, TRL_DATE
```

Actual results and expected results. Results with red line should now be shown because there's another STO_PART with a higher TRL_DATE

[image: description]
EDIT:

ROW_NUMBER query

```
SELECT      STO_PART, STO_PART_ORG, STO_STORE, BIS_BIN, TRL_ORDER, TRL_DATE

FROM        (SELECT STO_PART, STO_PART_ORG, STO_STORE, BIS_BIN, TRL_ORDER, TRL_DATE, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by STO_PART ORDER BY TRL_DATE DESC) as MAX_DATE
            FROM R5STOCK inner join R5PARTS on PAR_CODE = STO_PART and STO_PART_ORG = PAR_ORG
            inner join R5BINSTOCK on (BIS_STORE = STO_STORE and BIS_PART = STO_PART and BIS_PART_ORG = STO_PART_ORG)
            left join R5TRANSLINES on (TRL_PART = PAR_CODE and PAR_ORG = TRL_PART_ORG and TRL_TYPE = 'RECV')

WHERE       PAR_NOTUSED != '+' and BIS_QTY > 0 and STO_STORE in ('116-01', '138-05', '156-01', '216-01', '228-01', '282-01') 
            and TRL_STORE = STO_STORE and TRL_ORDER is not null) X

WHERE MAX_DATE = 1
```

Comment: That query doesn't have a `ROW_NUMBER`, so how do you know it doesn't work?  What did you try? Also you have a `GROUP BY` but no aggregate functions? This seems like a duplicate of [Find last row in group by query-SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15571471/find-last-row-in-group-by-query-sql-server).

Comment: It is a miskate while testing. I had MAX(TRL_DATE) on the query, but it didn't do much and I deleted it, but left GROUY BY, it can be deleted.

Comment: So, why didn't `ROW_NUNMBER` work here? I can't see why it wouldn't. Please do show your attempt and explain why it didn't work; otherwise (if you haven't tried), see the answer I linked above.

Comment: I don't know how to properly code it

Comment: What don't you understand about the linked answer then @Nanaki? Like I said, please do show your attempts, as this is clearly a duplicate. If you don't understand the linked answer, you should be asking about that. Otherwise you're not going to understand the answer your given and it will be useless to you; as you shouldn't use an answer you don't understand. WE don't support your SQL, you do, and if you don't understand your SQL, how do you support it?

Comment: @Larnu please see edit. I think I managed to do it. The results seems ok, but does it have a correct structure?

Comment: If it didn't have the correct "structure" (syntax?) the query wouldn't run. :)

Answer (score 0):

Creating a virtual field for your desired order within each partition usually works in cases like this.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
(
    SELECT      STO_PART, STO_PART_ORG, STO_STORE, BIS_BIN, TRL_ORDER, TRL_DATE,
            InvertedOrder = ROW_NUMBER() OVER PARTITION BY (STO_PART ORDER BY TRL_ORDER DESC)

    FROM        R5STOCK 
                inner join R5PARTS on PAR_CODE = STO_PART and STO_PART_ORG = PAR_ORG
                inner join R5BINSTOCK on (BIS_STORE = STO_STORE and BIS_PART = STO_PART and BIS_PART_ORG = STO_PART_ORG)
                left join R5TRANSLINES on (TRL_PART = PAR_CODE and PAR_ORG = TRL_PART_ORG and TRL_TYPE = 'RECV')

    WHERE       PAR_NOTUSED != '+' and BIS_QTY > 0 and STO_STORE in ('116-01', '138-05', '156-01', '216-01', '228-01', '282-01') 
                and TRL_STORE = STO_STORE and TRL_ORDER is not null

    GROUP BY    STO_PART, STO_PART_ORG, STO_STORE, BIS_BIN, TRL_ORDER, TRL_DATE
)
WHERE
    InvertedOrder=1
```