# Last entry for non-unique id where X=Y

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: Expected data]

Please see the above image for rows I would like returned, those highlighted in yellow.

From the picture attached, I would like it to only return id **133766** and **133792** as they end at **stage 5**.

I want to pull the last entry for a non-unique id where there could be X amount of entries per non-unique id.

I am not overly experience in SQL, but what I know is;

I could do

```
SELECT max(stage), id
FROM [dbo].[table] group by id
```

and this gives me a pretty good starting point. I'd rather sort on the date field, as the "stage" isn't actually an int, I've done that for simplicity here.

So I essentially need to get the last entry (figured out by date) for all non-unique id's where stage doesn't equal X

I feel like it's a really simple, everyday query, but I just can not wrap my head around a simple, efficient way to do it.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Add a `WHERE` to your query?

Comment: @Larnu, where stage=5 would still return 115599 ID but for when the stage was 5, I want only when 5 is the max.

Group by also adds limits with where clauses.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find last row in group by query-SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15571471/3484879)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to point out that `not exists` is also a way to approach this:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.stage = 5 and
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.id = t.id and t2.stage > t.stage
                 );
```

With an index on `(id, stage)`, you might be surprised at how good the performance is.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
SELECT * 
FROM(
SELECT Id, Stage, CompletionDate
    ,Row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY CompletionDate DESC) AS RN
FROM YourTable
) AS t
WHERE RN = 1 AND Stage = 5;
```

Comment: You're a gem!

Thank you, marked as correct answer, could you recommend where I could look to understand this?

Teaching a man how to fish and all that jazz, I would like to understand why this works, but I currently don't!

Comment: You are welcome @OANSI.. The `Row_Number` will generate a sequential number based on the partition column and orders based on the order by column.

Comment: is the best way to do this?

I was hoping to be able to transfer this through a few SQL variants, firebird to be more specific but it seems like firebird doesn't allow partition?

Comment: @OANSI, You weren't mention anywhere about `firebird`. Go with **Gordon's** answer. That will support all the SQLs.

Comment: I know, I just wanted to know peoples general approach to this /problem/. I figured it would be an easy fix, but I just couldnt get my head around it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the window version of `MAX`

```
;WITH CTE_DATA AS
(
  SELECT *
  , MAX(stage) OVER (PARTITION BY id) AS max_stage
  FROM [dbo].[table]
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE_DATA
WHERE stage = max_stage
  AND max_stage = 5;
```