# Query creates doubles on a specific column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created a query in SQL. When executing it, it works well, except when I add the `t4.CreatedOn` to be displayed. 
Here is the query

```sql
select 
    t1.OrderNo, 
    t1.ProdLineNo, 
    t1.ProdNo, 
    t1.LotNo,
    t2.ProductNo,
    t3.LotNo,
    convert(double precision, t3.QntCons),
    convert(varchar, t4.CreatedOn, 20),
    convert(varchar, t6.CreatedOn, 105)

from table1 t1
    join table2 t2 on 
        t1.ID = t2.ID 
    join table3 t3 on 
        t2.ID = t3.ID
    join table4 t4 on 
        t4.OrderNo = t1.OrderNo 
        and 
        t4.SrcLotNo = t3.LotNo 
        and 
        t4.SrcProdNo = t2.ProdNo
    join table5 t5 on 
        t2.ProdNo = t5.ProdNo 
    join table6 t6 on 
        t3.LotNo = t6.LotNo and t6.ProdID = t5.ID

where t1.OrderNo = '1020' and t4.Context like 'allocate%'
```

The problem is that after executing with the parameter above, when there are 2 or more products with the same `LotNo` each of them is linked with as many dates as there are in the same `LotNo`. Only one date is correct, while the other one should be only on the correct product.

To understand better the problem, that's the output I get

```
OrderNo | ... | ProdNo | ... | LotNo | QntCons | t4.CreatedOn | ...
1020    | ... |   39   | ... | 48-02 |    12   |  2020-02-03  | ...
1020    | ... |   39   | ... | 48-02 |    12   |  2020-02-04  | ...
1020    | ... |   40   | ... | 48-02 |    15   |  2020-02-03  | ...
1020    | ... |   40   | ... | 48-02 |    15   |  2020-02-04  | ...
1020    | ... |   41   | ... | 22-15 |    10   |  2020-01-20  | ...
```

Correct output should be:

```
OrderNo | ... | ProdNo | ... | LotNo | QntCons | t4.CreatedOn | ...
1020    | ... |   39   | ... | 48-02 |    12   |  2020-02-04  | ...
1020    | ... |   40   | ... | 48-02 |    15   |  2020-02-03  | ...
1020    | ... |   41   | ... | 22-15 |    10   |  2020-01-20  | ...
```

I don't know if that's caused because of a missing relation between my tables, or there is an extra one or the query is incorrect?

Comment: group by `lotno` and aggregate the correct date

Comment: There are 5 joins it is hard to say where the 1-to-many is being generated.  I would suggest comment out the joins and add them back one-by-one to see where the issue begins.

Comment: what's the critearia for the correct date ..?

Comment: @mxmissile after doing ```group by``` it makes no difference.
@BarbarosÖzhan in the table ```t4``` there  is a column with the ```ProdNo``` and ```CreatedOn```. One date is for each ```ProdNo```

Comment: This looks like it actually a duplicate of [Find last row in group by query-SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15571471/2029983)